# Increase the size of history for zsh

Tags: command-line, shell, zsh, history

I've reached the maximum 10K lines of commands in my `zsh` history file, but I want to store more commands.

So I set this, in my `~/.zshrc` file:

```
export HISTFILE="$HOME/.zsh_history"
export HISTSIZE=1000000000
export SAVEHIST=1000000000
setopt EXTENDED_HISTORY
```

And I made sure to run `source ~/.zshrc` after editing this file.

But when I `echo` these variables, I get different results:

[image: zsh history is limited]

And when I close the terminal and open a new session, I can see that the number of commands in my history file is 10K:

[image: Number of commands in zsh history is 10K again]

How can I fix it so that I can store more than 10K commands in my `~/.zsh_history` file?

Also, when I run `wc -l < $HISTFILE`, it gives me a number more than 10K:

[image]

What's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that this is not your entire `.zshrc` and that the variables are set somewhere else.

Make sure you're not using any other script that overwrites these variables, such as `oh-my-zsh` ([example](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/lib/history.zsh#L28)), and that you place your commands at the bottom of your config file.

Comment: I *was* using `oh-my-zsh` and placing the exports at the bottom fixed it. Thank you.